# Use of "then" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

"What you hold in your hand, ***then***, is a written record of my..."

Is the word 'then' in the above sentence means 'thus, consequently, as suggested in the similar but little different theard ["the use of then"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178247/use-of-then-in-the-sentence)

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same usage. There has been a description or discussion of the item held in your hand in a previous sentence or passage and this sentence is a summary of the conclusion of that discussion.

Comment: @boldben surely your comment deserves to be a definitive answer?

Comment: Thankyou for your time!